# How can I get those images shown in MessageDlg?

Tags: delphi, dialog, delphi-2009

I want to make my own MessageDlg because the standard one does not have what I need. Is there a way to get those images (Error, Information, Warning...) and show them in my new MessageDlg ?

Comment: Use LoadIcon to obtain these standard icons.

Comment: Great ! Thanks ! But these icons will have the same size in all windows versions ?

Comment: Will they? Why do you ask?

Comment: No. They doesn't have to. It's just upon the [TaskDialogIndirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-taskdialogindirect) Windows API function how to display the dialog.

Comment: Btw. what you are missing? The message dialog is quite flexible on modern OS.

Comment: Victoria, it's complicated to explain, but thanks to David I have succeeded to make my new message dialog with `LoadIcon`. That icon was the only thing I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At David's suggestion, here's how I did:

```
procedure TSaveErrorDlg.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var Ico: TIcon;
begin
 Ico:= TIcon.Create;
 Ico.Handle:= LoadIcon(0, IDI_ERROR);
 if Ico.HandleAllocated then Image.Picture.Assign(Ico);
 Ico.Free;
end;
```